# UWP MVVM concurrent ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, multithreading, uwp

In my program i have one page with viewmodel. Viewmodel executes Update function every 10 sec in another thread with a Timer:

```
// in viewmodel ctor
var timer = new Timer(Update, 0, 10000);

public ObservableCollection<Tick> Data { get; set; }

public void Update(object state)
{
    var query = xbtceService.GetAllTicksAsync(); // get data from service
    query.Wait();
    var data = query.Result;
    if (data.Any())
    {
        dataAccess.SaveItems(data); //save data in database
    }

    Data.Clear(); // ERROR, another thread
    var list = dataAccess.LoadList();
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        Data.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Also viewmodel have `ObservableCollection` that Binded to a `ListView`. How to fill `ObservableCollection` from another thread with new data every 10 sec?

Answer (score 0):

You should use DispatcherTimer,and if have the async want use ui,you can

```
           await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
            () =>
            {
                //code
            });
```

Comment: Any way to update collection with mvvm pattern?

Comment: You can add in ViewModel

Answer (score 0):

[System.Threading.Timer Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) provides a mechanism for executing a method on a thread pool thread at specified intervals. And once you bind `Data` to a `ListView`, `Data` is associated with the UI thread. In UWP, we can't access UI thread form a worker thread directly. So as @lindexi said, we need to use [CoreDispatcher.RunAsync method](http://CoreDispatcher.RunAsync%20method) to schedule work on the UI thread. For example, you can change your `Update` method like following:

```
public async void Update(object state)
{
    var query = xbtceService.GetAllTicksAsync(); // get data from service
    query.Wait();
    var data = query.Result;
    if (data.Any())
    {
        dataAccess.SaveItems(data); //save data in database
    }

    await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        Data.Clear();
        var list = dataAccess.LoadList();
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            Data.Add(item);
        }
    });
}
```